# Change institution and country of PhD, after year 1, how to present this to a prospective supervisor?

Tags: phd, university, supervision, transfer-student

I am in the start of my second year of PhD studies. I have identified a gap in the literature, a research question and half way thorough my research proposal. Unfortunately, the rising costs of living, electricity and the extreme housing crisis in the country have rendered our already low (350 euros below minimum wage) stipend as non-relevant anymore. Some PhD students need to work part-time and thus affecting both our output and health, especially mature students. Therefore, I decided to change country, I identified several programs and I am planning to email prospective supervisors regarding my research. How do I go about discussing this situation (also in my application), is this a valid reason and should I even mention it? Any advice would be more than welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems to me to be a good reason to want to move and should be easy to explain to any potential supervisor. It would be especially helpful if you can get the support of your current supervisor in whatever changes need to be made.

I'd suggest you have a talk with them about the financial situation and how it puts your continuing at risk. Maybe they have some other options to increase your funding. And, a note from them saying "I hate to lose this person, but the financial situation here is untenable." would be a big plus.

As in any application, however, focus mainly on your skills and what you can bring to the new place. You need to find a good fit, which can be harder unless you can start over.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mention the current financial situation in your application or make it the center of your discussion with new, potential supervisors. While it is an important consideration for you, it might distract the conversation from your research program and how your work could fit in (at the new institution, with the new supervisor, etc). You really want to highlight how you'll fit there with your work, not why it's a more affordable place to live. (Obviously, if it naturally comes up, you should be honest, but I wouldn't lead with it.)